# Convert date in numerical format to a date/time format

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have a date but as a continuous number [YY][MM][DD] like for example 820401 for April 1 1982. Is there an easy way to convert it to the actual date format?

Comment: What is the _actual date format_?

Comment: hi @Roman please check my code it will definitely work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your values are in `yymmdd` format. You can use `DateSerial` function for this. Will work in Access SQL and in VBA.

```
DateSerial(mid(DateField,1,2),mid(DateField,3,2),mid(DateField,5,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use do this the numerical way:

```
NumDate = 860401
TrueDate = DateSerial(NumDate \ 10000, NumDate \ 100 Mod 100, NumDate Mod 100)

TrueDate -> #1986-04-01#
```

Comment: For yy <= 31 this will fail, it will interpret 300401 as `2001-04-30`, at least on German windows and date format.

Comment: Yes, forgot that, thanks. _DateSerial_ is the safe method - and it can be done without string handling. See edited answer, please.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this `sql query` it will definitely work fine for you.

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 820401
SELECT CONCAT (
        DATEPART(MMM, LEFT(@i, 3, 4))
        ,DATEPART(dd, RIGHT(@i, 2))
        ,DATEPART(YYYY, LEFT(@i, 2))
        )
```

Comment: Note the [ms-access] tag.